# Does initial-scale=1.0 prevent zooming in on a Web page?

Tags: html

I know `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1>` simply sets the initial zoom level to 1. However, I have also heard that `initial-scale=1.0` prevents zooming on Web pages. Is this true and are there any other settings I should add besides `content=width=device-width`, `initial-scale=1`/`initial-scale=1.0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `initial-scale` won’t prevent scaling.

Using `user-scalable=no` is what would prevent scaling.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag):

> The initial-scale property controls the zoom level when the page is first loaded. The maximum-scale, minimum-scale, and user-scalable properties control how users are allowed to zoom the page in or out.

So in a nutshell, `initial-scale` just controls the initial zoom level of a webpage, just as the name suggests.